# How to Improve on this Entity Framework Query

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

- Applicant : Person
- PhoneNumber
- PhoneType

The applicant is derived from `Person`. The `Applicant` has many `PhoneNumber`s (up to three). Each `PhoneNumber` has only 1 `PhoneType`.

```
public class Applicant : Person
{    
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber 
{                        
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(17)]
    public string Number { get; set; }    

    public int PhoneTypeId { get; set; }            

    public virtual PhoneType PhoneType { get; set; }

}

public class PhoneType 
{     
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

It seems to me that the two queries I am using could be merged and the foreach loop eliminated, but I already have a large number of joins in the first query and I am not sure how to merge them. The question is a two part question:

1. How could I merge the two queries and
2. If I don't merge the queries, how could I improve upon the `PhoneNumber` / `PhoneType` query.

The goal is to return an `Applicant` with a list of `PhoneNumber`s, and each `PhoneNumber` with a `PhoneType`.  For clarity the types are : Home, Office and Mobile.

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/* Obtain the Applicant                     */
/*------------------------------------------*/
IQueryable<Applicant> applicantQuery = 
      DbContext.Applicants.Where(a => a.CreatedBy == userId)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.Address)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.Address.StateProvince)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.PhoneNumbers)                                                
               .Include(applicant => applicant.HomeChurch)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.HomeChurch.Address)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.HomeChurch.Address.StateProvince)
               .Include(applicant => applicant.TripApplication);

Applicant applicant = applicantQuery.FirstOrDefault<Applicant>();

if (applicant != null && applicant.PhoneNumbers != null)
{
    IQueryable<PhoneType> phoneTypeQuery = DbContext.Set<PhoneType>();
    List<PhoneType> phoneTypes = phoneTypeQuery.ToList<PhoneType>();

    foreach (PhoneNumber ph in applicant.PhoneNumbers)
    {
        ph.PhoneType = (phoneTypes.Where(pt => pt.Id == ph.PhoneTypeId)).First();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you might give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core supports loading multiple levels by combining *Include()* with *ThenInclude()*, more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)

To load the Phone along with PhoneTypes your query should look like this (I removed the rest of the relations for clarity):

```
var applicant = DbContext.Applicants.Where(a => a.CreatedBy == userId)
        .Include(applicant => applicant.PhoneNumbers)                                                
        .ThenInclude(phone => phone.PhoneType)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you E-Bat. I will give it a try.

Comment: Again thank you. I not only made it work, but in the process learned a new technique.

Comment: @Andy, glad to help, next step to improve your application is to use async methods, like FirstOrDefautlAsync() ;)

Comment: Yup, I know. I was lazy when I wrote the BusinessLogicLayer and RepositoryLayer.

Comment: you guilted me. The entire repository layer as well as business logic layer is now a sync.